# Language Evolution: Use of 'It'

Tags: language-evolution

If, as it is written in Oxford Dictionaries, 'it' can be [used to identify a person, 'it’s me', 'it’s a boy'](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/it), why are 'she' and 'he' still used and, furthermore, why are people still discussing as to whether they should be replaced with the singular 'they'?

If any, let us use 'it' then, no?

Under a different point of view, do you, expert minds of EL&U, think that the use of 'she' and 'he', the last barricade of gender in English, is declining and that 'it' is taking their place?

Comment: So you think that grammatically, it should have been: ***It's a bird! It's a plane! He's Superman!*** … that doesn't work at all. This type of use of *it* has been around for a long time, is quite distinct from the regular uses of *he* and *she*, and is not going to replace them.

Comment: @Peter, no, I think that it could be 'It's a bird! It's a plane! It's Superman!', but, really, I don't know, this is why I asked. However, as a non-native, I don't see anything incorrect saying 'It's Elberich' or 'It's Peter'. After all, 'it' can work better than the singular 'they'.

Comment: Language just doesn't decide one day that it's changing from pattern A to pattern B. Also there's no necessity to go in a particular direction; it may go towards B, stop halfway, move back, maybe turn towards C, and then all the A speakers have a war against all the D speakers but then acquire what D speakers say in a very limited context, and then something else happens.

Comment: Also, I don't think 'he' or 'she' are being replaced by 'it', and I don't think they are barricades, or the last ones of gender.

Answer (score 6):

*It* in such cases is used only because the clause would otherwise be without a subject. Its use here is quite different from the use of *he* and *she*. French has *C’est moi*, where *C’* has the same role. Your name suggests you might be a German speaker. How would you say *It’s me* in German?

The question of *they* referring to a singular antecedent is a separate matter.  It has been 
asked many times here, and you may like to search the site to see the answers given.

No, it is certainly not the case that *it* is taking the place of *he* and *she*.

Comment: +1, but I don't understand '*It* in such cases is used only because the clause would otherwise be without a subject,' because, if I were the speaker, then, in the lack of a subject, I could use 'he' or 'she', 'he's me', 'he's a boy'; nonetheless OED says 'it's me' and 'it's a boy' are correct. So, what do you precisely mean with '*otherwise*'? 'otherwise' what?

Comment: @ElberichSchneider That's not the OED, although the OED of course also documents this usage (in more detail, though it doesn't appear to include examples like "it's me").

Comment: @snail, please see meaning #2 at this page http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/it

Comment: @ElberichSchneider Yes, thank you, I've already seen it.  For future reference, Oxford publishes more than one dictionary; only one of those is properly referred to as the Oxford English Dictionary (OED).  It has its own website, which you can find [here](http://www.oed.com/).

Comment: I mean that otherwise it would be _is me_, which is ungrammatical. You can, of course, say _He is a boy_ as well as _It's a boy_, but it means something different. May I ask again if your native language is German?

Comment: @Barrie, the German equivalent of _It's me_ is _Ich bin es_, usually contracted to _Ich bin's_ (= _I am it_).

Comment: Then let's stick with the French _C'est moi_ as an analogy.

Comment: Shouldn't the example be "It is I."?  Or "I am he."

Comment: Why? Does anyone say either of those? Normal English is _It's me_ and _It's him_.

Answer (score 1):

It seems (pun intended) that **it** used as the subject, to stand in for a gender specific predicate nominative, occurs most frequently when the listener knows that someone or something is present or imminent, but does not know specifically who or what that someone or something is.

In **It's a boy!**, presumably the listener knew a child was expected, but may have been uncertain of the gender (especially since the idiom developed well before gender screening). **It** (the child-sex-unknown) has been revealed to be a male.

Similarly, the sky-scanners are not sure what **it** is - perhaps a bird (gender indifferent), or a plane (neuter, notwithstanding military naming traditions)? On closer scrutiny, **it** turns out to be a *him* (or maybe a *her* if *Supergirl* is the spotted Krytonian heroine).